# Existence of a point with positive definite Hessian

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and open. Let $f\in C^2(\overline{U})$. Assume $f=0$ on $\partial U$ and $f(x_0)<0$ for some point $x_0\in \mathring{U}$.

Obviously $f$ attains its minimum in $\mathring{U}$ and the Hessian is positive semi-definite there. However, is there also always a point $x_1\in \mathring{U}$ such that the Hessian at $x_1$ is positive definite?

Comment: are you looking for a condition for the Hessian to be positive definite, or are you asking if there is such a point, with the given information?

Comment: The latter. Notice the difference between the described (trivial) positive SEMI-DEFINITENESS in the minimum and the desired positive DEFINITENESS in some other point